# C# new pages are written on the first page, instead of creating new pages

Tags: c#, printing

I try to create a code which needs to print a data hold in a two dimensional list object. The size of the array is larger than to fit on one page. I use hasMorePages to create new pages.

I keep my counter outside the print code block. The problem is not having the same page written. Instead I have the data of the first page, and when it needs two print the second page, it uses the first page to print the new data. So I just have one page to be printed.

When I debug, I see the hasMorePages becomes true, to printPage event starts again, but still writes on the same page.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
    List<List<string>> sifirlamaPrintList; //this holds the data to print
        int rowIndexForPrinting;
        int page;

        private void printSifirlama_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintListCreation(); //this method gets the data to print
            rowIndexForPrinting = 0;
            page = 1;

            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

            // Set the page orientation to Landscape
            printDocumentSifirlama.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocumentSifirlama.PrintPage += printDocumentSifirlama_PrintPage;
                printDocumentSifirlama.PrinterSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings;
                printDocumentSifirlama.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                printDocumentSifirlama.Print();
            }
        }

        private void printDocumentSifirlama_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            float headerHeight = 60; // Height of the header row
            int dataCellHeight = 45; // Height of the data rows

            List<int> columnWidths = new List<int>() { 50, 50, 50, 100, 175, 100, 175, 250, 75 };
            List<string> columnHeadersList = new List<string>() { "Id", "GNo", "UNo", "Rtb", "Name", "Rtb", "Ad Soyad", "Unit", "Row" };

            // Define the font for the header
            Font headerFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);

            // Draw the header row
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                RectangleF cellRect = new RectangleF(x, y, columnWidths[i], headerHeight);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(cellRect));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(columnHeadersList[i], headerFont, Brushes.Black, cellRect, new StringFormat
                {
                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                });
                x += columnWidths[i];
            }

            y += headerHeight;

            // Define the font for the data rows
            Font dataFont = new Font("Arial", 10);

            // Draw the data rows
            while (rowIndexForPrinting < sifirlamaPrintList.Count)
            {
                x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
                for (int i = 0; i < sifirlamaPrintList[rowIndexForPrinting].Count; i++)
                {
                    RectangleF cellRect = new RectangleF(x, y, columnWidths[i], dataCellHeight);
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(cellRect));
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(sifirlamaPrintList[rowIndexForPrinting][i], dataFont, Brushes.Black, cellRect, new StringFormat
                    {
                        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    });
                    x += columnWidths[i]; 
                }
                y += dataCellHeight; 

                rowIndexForPrinting++;

                // Check if there is enough space for another row; if not, set HasMorePages to true
                if (y + dataCellHeight > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    page++;
                    return;
                }
            }

            // If we reach here, there are no more rows to print
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }

    }
```

I can't understand why the code not starts to print a second page even if the "private void printDocumentSifirlama_PrintPage" method starts again